# Programmatically add web app shortcut to macOS Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I'm working on adding an app icon to the Dock programmatically. But all the information I found indicates I need to restart the Dock after the change.

Is there any possible method that can add icon to the Dock "live" that doesn't need to kill the Dock process? Can I perhaps use Mach IPC?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following AppleScript. It worked on my system.

```
my add_item_to_dock(choose file of type {"APPL"} with prompt "Choose an application to add to the Dock:")
on add_item_to_dock(item_path)
    try
        get item_path as alias -- you need a POSIX path so this coerces the path in case it's an HFS path, alias, file ref, etc.
        set item_path to POSIX path of item_path
    end try
    try
        tell application "Dock" to quit
    end try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>" & item_path & "</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'"
    try
        tell application "Dock" to activate
    end try
end add_item_to_dock
```

This entry will be stored in ~/Library/Preference/com.apple.dock.plist

Hope this will be helpful.